# cannot install anything via apt-get. problem with apt-get update

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I am unable to install anything with apt-get. I think this problem is due to gpg error of some kind. I have done almost everything on the net as per my belief. This is what happens when I run `apt-get update`.

```
mody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http:/dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                  
Get:2 http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                      
Ign http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                        
E: GPG error: http:/dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
mody@ubuntu:~$
```

**I tried these**

```
mody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get clean
mody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Get:1 http:/dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Get:2 http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                      
Ign http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                        
E: GPG error: http:/dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

**Didn't work**

```
mody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True
Get:1 http:/dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Get:2 http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                      
Ign http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                        
E: GPG error: http:/dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

**Didn't work**

```
mody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true 
Get:1 http:/dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Get:2 http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                      
Ign http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                        
E: GPG error: http:/dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
mody@ubuntu:~$
```

**Even this**

Click System>>Administration>>Software Sources
Click the Download From menu and choose Main Server
Type the following in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Run the update manager again.

**But did not work**

I also changed the sources with one available on ubuntu site. i dont know why i did that but that didn't help

**Did a force update. problem persists.**

```
mody@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update -f

[sudo] password for mody: 
Get:1 http:/dl.google.com stable Release.gpg
Get:2 http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                      
Ign http:/dl.google.com stable Release                                        
E: GPG error: http:/dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

**Frustrated.**

Synaptic is not installed as well as aptitude. changing download server to everything possible from anything did not help either.

PS: link were giving me problem with posting so I delete `/` where `//` were present

Comment: @Azker as this `sudo apt-get install -f` command do a force update?

Comment: edit your question and post the output of 'cat /etc/apt/sources.list' and 'ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/'. I'm sure there are some left entries in those directories. You can also go to  System>>Administration>>Software Sources and on tab Other Software uncheck all with dl.google.com

Comment: **EDIT:** Try a force update > `sudo apt-get update -f` .. @AvinashRaj - thank you for pointing out.

Comment: -f, --fix-broken
           Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.@Azker -f doesn't means for force.

Comment: @arhimed that did it. thanks a ton!!   System>>Administration>>Software Sources and on tab Other Software uncheck all with dl.google.com

Answer (score 3):

The key for signing downloaded packages from the google Linux software repository may need to be re-imported. This can be done with the following line in a terminal

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Alternatively we can also download and save the key to then import it manually.

Source: [Google](http://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)