# Can't update my system due to GPG error Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA'

Tags: apt, 14.04, updates

I can't update...

I have been trying to troubleshoot this problem for a while now... The only way I found is to re-install Ubuntu...

```
sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=true
0% [Connecting to mirror.bytemark.co.uk (212.110.161.69)] [Connecting to archivGET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.canonical.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Mon, 02 Jun 2014 21:50:58 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


0% [Connecting to mirror.bytemark.co.uk (212.110.161.69)] [Waiting for headers]GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: mirror.bytemark.co.uk
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:11:36 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: extras.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:19:18 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


GET /appgrid/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: ppa.launchpad.net
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 14:53:42 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


GET /torproject.org/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: deb.torproject.org
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 30 May 2014 11:28:02 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 213
Date: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:20:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease [213 B]                        
94% [1 InRelease gpgv 213 B] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] [WaitiSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/extras.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InRIgn http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
E: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
superuser@dude-X202E:~$ sudo apt-get update -o Debug::Acquire::http=true
0% [Working]GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.canonical.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Mon, 02 Jun 2014 21:50:58 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: extras.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:21:27 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)

GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:08:34 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)



GET /appgrid/stable/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: ppa.launchpad.net
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
Range: bytes=213-
If-Range: Thu, 05 Jun 2014 14:53:42 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


GET /torproject.org/dists/trusty/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: deb.torproject.org
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
If-Modified-Since: Fri, 30 May 2014 11:28:02 GMT
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 213
Date: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:21:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease [213 B]
94% [1 InRelease 213 B/213 B 100%] [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers] GET /ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease HTTP/1.1
Host: archive.ubuntu.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/*
User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.0.1ubuntu2)


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 213
Date: Sat, 07 Jun 2014 00:21:32 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Get:2 http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease [213 B]                        
97% [1 InRelease gpgv 213 B] [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.92.200)]Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_InIgn http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                 
E: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

Comment: Did you solved the problem after the reinstallation?

Comment: It appears the problem isn't so much GPG as the fact that you feed it no data. Connection issues? Empty (in error of course) signature file on remote end?

Comment: Can you post the output of `wget -O - -S http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease`

Comment: See [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Answer (score 6):

When I was running **sudo apt-get update** I got the error:

```
Ign http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                              
E: GPG error: http://br.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

To solve that, first I tried:

```
wget https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8850924/fixpackage
chmod +x ./fixpackage
sudo ./fixpackage
```

As recomended in 
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/251767

But it didn't work for me. So finally I tried the following lines and it solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists.broke
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This solution does not work on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04.4 on Ubuntu on Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, but after enabling internet traffic from/to (system) through the firewall solved the issue.