# problem after apt-get update command

Tags: apt, updates, software-center, update-manager, ubuntu-tweak

Recently , i tried to install google earth from Ubuntu tweak . the programme asked me to add the repository of google earth . well,after i do the command i found that an error message that told me that i couldn't add the source and the system can't build packages tree.i run in terminal `sudo apt-get update`
and i found following Errors:

```
Fetched 143 kB in 3min 43s (637 B/s)                                           
Reading package lists... Error!
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 6AF0E1940624A220 Launchpad PPA for TualatriX
W: GPG error: http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/eg.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I can't launch Ubuntu software center.and a minus mark appear in bar at the top of the screen . please tell me what should i do in steps please.i have Ubuntu 14.04 trusty tahr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the GPG errors, run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6AF0E1940624A220 40976EAF437D05B5` to import the keys.

For the MergeList problem, run `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`.

Finally, run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: grasias amigo,i ran apt-get update after i do what you say. first i met a little error,i ran it again and every thing is ok.ubuntu center worked again and the red mark has gone away.

Comment: i get this:E: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Comment: and this:W: GPG error: http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

Comment: do they the same solution or not?

Comment: take that too W: Failed to fetch http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

Comment: @user297975: The GPG warning about the invalid signature should have been gone. For the failed to fetch warning, you can ignore that, since it's just a translation file. For the NODATA error, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication) for a possible answer.

Comment: thanks,but if i face another GpG error ,i should type the same command or i should change something.failed to fetch warning does it have any bad effects on the system i face it alot.

Comment: sorry i have tired you. but the problem back again the red mark back ,ubuntu center doesnot work 'apt-get update'output is 'W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_main_source_Sources  Hash Sum mismatch'sorryyy again for Disturbance

Comment: gpg error again. it seems to be disease.

Comment: the command about mergelist problem output this'rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/eg.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_i18n_Translation-en%5fUS’: No such file or directory'after doing the first command on your answer

Comment: help me anybody.

Comment: For the GPG missing publickey/BADSIG error, try `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys` followed by whatever keys appear. For the mergelist problem, run `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists*` instead.

Comment: it doesn't work in terminal .i went to apt and found a file named lists should i remove all files on it. i can by giving the file the permission from this command chmod 0777 _the directory_ i should remove files which written on html or remove any thing on this file

Comment: i found this in terminal rm: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Is a directory

Comment: @user297975: First off, don't change permissions of directories unless you know why you're doing it and that you really need to do it. Second, I had a slight typo in the command I posted in my comment; it should be `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. Third, the error message is fine; the `partial` directory can stay.

Comment: thanks , i gave up i install the system again.thanks again for your patience .

Comment: Does downloading the gpg key without checking it open you up to man in the middle attacks?  What sort of checking should be performed to be sure that the key you're adding is what it's supposed to be?

Comment: @mc0e: It might, under certain circumstances. If you specify only the last 8 hex characters of the key, and there happens to be a collision, you might get the wrong key. But even then, though, the repo will still be considered untrusted because the key you downloaded is a different key. I'm not a security expert, so take what I said with a grain of salt. Also, you might be better off asking/searching over on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the instructions from [saiarcot895](https://askubuntu.com/users/241580/saiarcot895) :

For an error like this

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release:
The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG [ some_number ] 
Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

do this - preferably one instruction at a time -

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys [ some_number ]
cd /var/lib/apt
ls -la
sudo mv lists lists_bak
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get update
```

which is roughly

1. call `gpg` via `apt-key` via `apt-get`, to download a new key
2. go to where `apt` keeps its data
3. look at the data that `apt` has at the moment
4. rename the `apt` cache directory to both back it up and clear the cache
5. make a new `apt` cache directory
6. update the cache of packages that `apt` knows about