# apt-get update: "GPG error: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA'"

Tags: apt, gnupg

after running 'sudo apt-get update'
I see this in terminal:
[image: sudo apt-get update shows error]

Comment: Please copy (select with mouse and press CTRL+SHIFT+C in the terminal) and paste ([edit] your question) command outputs as text instead of as screenshot. It's better readable and editable and it produces less unnecessary internet traffic which consumes energy. Save the planet! :-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but its saying that I need more reputation to post more than two links!!(Sorry, I am unable to do so!)

Comment: You just have to correctly format it as code: Select the output in the [edit]or and press CTRL+K or click the **`{}`** button. You could also manually indent every line with 4 spaces. That way it will work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)