# Unable to update my VM Ubuntu Server 14.04 through source list, Any fix?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I have installed Ubuntu server 14.04 on virtual box along with putty and Winscp for ftp requirements.I need to install some packages in to that but if I write

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

... it gives "`Unable to locate the package`".
However if I simply use:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then also it returns error

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It seems there is some issue with sources.list file, I have already checked it with possibilities of errors but could not find any fix for that.
Can anybody help me out of this.
Thanks

Comment: Could you check if you can resolve the server name using `nslookup security.ubuntu.com` and reach it using `ping security.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Yes i can do that Server:         4.2.2.2
Address:        4.2.2.2#53

Comment: The `nslookup` output should contain several lines like this: `Name: security.ubuntu.com` `Address: 91.189.88.149` - doesn't it?

Comment: Yes those lines are there.

Comment: I am getting this error when I am using apt-get updateE: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Comment: Then please look at this question and follow the proposed solutions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication

Comment: I gone through the link but could not find any solution from there

Comment: What do you mean by "could not find any solution from there"? You tried all the given solutions and still get the NODATA error? Did you already try a different internet connection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)