# How install git in ubuntu

Tags: git

i want to install git on my ubuntu
i use this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

but it's take error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: What is the ubuntu version? Do you use a PPA?

Comment: i use ubuntu 15.10

Comment: `liberror-perl` is available in the repos. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: i couldn't use the update command , give me this error : E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Comment: It does not mean "you could not use this command". There is a problem with Chrome repo for some reason. It is another issue.

Comment: i wanna say it's doesn't work for me , i know it's another issue , but How i fix this

Comment: It looks like a network problem. Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: no i don't use proxy

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove <package name>
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

If doesn't work :

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install GIT :

```
 sudo apt-get install git
```