# Jetson Tegra TX1 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, sudo, cuda

I am trying to update using sudo apt-get update on my Jetson Tegra TX1 but I am getting the following error..

E: GPG error: http://ports.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)

Tried different things but it didnt help.

Comment: What other different things did you do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have internet connection.
Try to use

```
wget http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/
```

and see what you'll get