# sudo apt-get update does not run

Tags: apt, google-chrome

Here is what I get

```
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable InRelease [1.487 B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [58,5 kB]
42% [2 InRelease gpgv 1.487 B] [3 Release 23,0 kB/58,5 kB 39%] 
[Waiting for heaSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stabIgn http://dl.google.com stable InRelease       
E: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I tried to remove chrome and reinstall it again but the problem does not seem to be from there.

Answer (score 0):

I found out thanks to Zanna for mentioning the duplication and the solution by [Anto](https://askubuntu.com/a/571675/673412). There are some problems with the ppa of google chrome in /etc/apt/sources.list.d which had to be removed.